# RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received

Tags: git, docker, ubuntu, unreal-engine4, wsl-2

I am getting the error in the below image when trying to clone a build of ue4 into docker using wsl2 ubuntu.

I have tried running the error command using an ssh link instead of the https one however that gives me an authentication error. I'm using a personal access token instead of my password to run this however I have tried with the password as well and that hasn't worked either. Any help is greatly appreciated, happy to provide anymore info if needed
[image]

Edit: In control panel my password for github is set to my personal access token currently
Edit 2: After a few minutes of cloning this was the output using ssh:
[image]

Edit 3: I have tried every solution I could find for the cURL error and haven't been able to find any solutions, the same goes for the unreachable network. Any help would be amazing I'm way over my head haha

Comment: This kind of thing usually means some badly behaved antivirus or security software or middleware box is corrupting your https sessions. You can try using ssh instead of https, or see if you can use a box that doesn't break web access. (Though admittedly, disabling all web access certainly improves the security...)

Comment: @torek I'm not worried about security for this system at all, it's only being used for internal testing but I'm not sure how I would go about locating the problem software/setting and disabling it do you have any advice? I don't have an antivirus software installed on this PC. I've tried using ssh but that gave me a different error although I can't remember which one, I'll rerun it and update you with the output. Thank you for your reply

Comment: "Network is unreachable" means that someone decided to cut off your access to GitHub. Maybe this happened while your earlier download was running, leading to the RPC failure. (For debugging your network, you need a different Q&A site.)